# Perform GUI method action inside of the subscribe method ANGULAR

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component which appears as a Modal (appears above any content on my web-site), this component works as a register component. It has a register form inside of it, and submits data to the service. Everything about submitting data works, everything is successfully stored in my database.

But the problem appears when I want to close my modal. I tried performing the method to close the modal like this in a third callback of subscribe method:

```
this.userService.store(this.user).subscribe(
      () => {
        // Inform the user
        this.success = 'Created successfully';

        // Reset the form
        this.registerForm.reset();
      },
      (err) => (this.error = err),
      () => {
        // Close the register form
        document.getElementById('closeButton').click(); <- FUNCTION WHICH PERFORMS THE CLOSE GUI METHOD
      }
    );
```

I also tried calling the method inside of the first callback of subscribe method:

```
this.userService.store(this.user).subscribe(
      () => {
        // Inform the user
        this.success = 'Created successfully';

        // Reset the form
        this.registerForm.reset();

        // Close the register form
        document.getElementById('closeButton').click(); <- FUNCTION WHICH PERFORMS THE CLOSE GUI METHOD
      },
      (err) => (this.error = err)
    );
```

None of this worked, I can call this method outside of the subscribe function but I want to close this component only if the response that comes from the server is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

There was no problem with this function nor calling the function within the subscribe method. Error that was happening inside of the service component blocked the execution of this method. Solving that error solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `finalize` operator. In case of http subscriptions, it is executed always at the end (simulates `finally` block from `try-catch` )

```
this.userService.store(this.user)
.pipe(
   finalize(()=>closeYourModal())
).subscribe(...usualStuff)
```

I always uses that to do finaization stuff (eg setting `inProgress` flag to false)